# Angular creates a non native array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ng-file-upload

When I populate model.files directly in my view with

```
<input type="file" ng-model= vm.files[0]>
<input type="file" ng-model= vm.files[1]>
```

my vm.files looks like this (example A):

[image]

And I need like this (example B):

[image]

In order to obtain example B, I have to do `vm.files = new Array()` in my controller.

I would like to know the difference between the array in example A, and the array in example B ?

Are there 2 types of arrays in javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not "2 types of arrays" in JavaScript, and this is not "creating a non native array".  It is creating an Object `files` with Properties `0` and `1`.  This is called `Object Bracket Notation`, and it occurs in Angular because Angular treats every property as an object unless it is defined otherwise ahead of time;  You are correct that you need to use `vm.files = new Array()` to **pre-allocate** `files` as an array.

Answer (score 1):

*Are there 2 types of arrays in javascript ?* Nope.

The first example it's a **javascript object** with two properties: `0` and `1`.

The second example it's the **javascript array** with two elements: the first and the second.

The diferrences are many: for example, the array type has the classic `splice`, `push` and `pop` methods. For all the differences, i suggest you to follow [this](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them) tutorial (and to learn some basic javascript on your own, too).